# how to make assert output be logged to file?

Tags: python, logging, assert

How to send the all `assert` methods output to a log file using a logger? The output usually goes to `std.err`. Maybe it is necessary to create a handler, but I did not manage to do that.

Here is the simple code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import unittest
import logging
import logging.config


# create logger
logging.config.fileConfig('example.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('examplelogger')

logger.info("test 1")

class TestUpper(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('fooo'.upper(), 'FOO')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and the logger configuration file I used:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,examplelogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[logger_examplelogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler
qualname=examplelogger
propagate=0

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('example.log', 'w')

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

The output from running the code is presented bellow. I'd like to save it (also) in the log file.

```
./example.py 
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_upper (__main__.TestUpper)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./example.py", line 16, in test_upper
    self.assertEqual('fooo'.upper(), 'FOO')
AssertionError: 'FOOO' != 'FOO'
- FOOO
?    -
+ FOO


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really enjoyed your question I learn a lot looking for solutions,

I have made a decorator that is maybe what you are looking for.
I believe I answer your question title, not the last question you asked.
IMO you should ask a second question for it because is not the same.

```
import unittest
import logging.config
from functools import wraps

def test_logger(logger):
    """
    Decorator for unitest that output assertion Error In a logger file

    :param logger: a logger
    :return:
    """
    def deco(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args):
            try:
                f(*args)
            except AssertionError as assErr:
                # f_name = (f.__name__) f_name is the function name of the function being decorated could be usefull
                # assErr is the message of the assertion Error
                # you can do more formatting here
                logger.info(assErr)  # send to the log

                raise  # if you don't raise the Error the test will be a success


        return wrapper
    return deco


logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('examplelogger')

logger.info("test 1")


class TestUpper(unittest.TestCase):

    @test_logger(logger)
    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('fooo'.upper(), 'FOO')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Hope it helps,

EDIT:
After running this very code a log file is created 'test.log' here is content:

```
INFO:examplelogger:test 1
INFO:examplelogger:'FOOO' != 'FOO'
- FOOO
?    -
+ FOO
```

The code capture an exception if raised by the assert and put it in the log. is that not what you asked for?

Comment: unfortunately this code does not save the messages generated by assert methods in the log file...

Comment: Strange, In my case it output it in the "test.log" file. I Edit my answer to shows my output.

Comment: well... sorry... in the small toy-example it did work fine... something else might be messing up with my actual scenario

Comment: =S Sorry about that, if you find a way to improve your example, some one may find another way. by the way, if another exception is raised (not an AssertionError) It will not be catched here you may want to add other excepts in the try except block.